# java kafka get message offset in partition by unique key

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If all my kafka messages contains a unique key, what will be the **fastest way** to query the offset of a message with its unique key within a partition in the broker? Assume I already know this message must exists in this broker and this partition.

One way I can think about for example is reprocessing all messages within the partition, and stop until the specific key is found. But if you have more than a million messages, processing each is really a waste of time.

In other word, is there any kafka API that can do this check directly on Kafka server?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka works like you guessed, it reads messages sequentially. You cannot go directly to some records. But what you can do to save time is to make many partitions for that topic, then by having the key you know what is the partition(you must google it how to get partition number) and then  you consume only from that partition. So say if you have `1 000 000` records in a topic, then if you make `100` partitions, you have to scan only `10 000` records and find yours.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/):

Use KStream.[transform()](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#transform-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TransformerSupplier-java.lang.String...-) and through [ProcessorContext](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorContext.html) get an access to a message offset. Then build KTable on top of result or use [Interactive Queries](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html).

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get your idea. So how would you like to get "a certain message offset" after it is already being consumed without reading the data from beginning? Via the ProcessorContext.offset() seems only give you the current messages offset

Comment: Am I correct: you would like to get a message stored in Kafka by its unique key?

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking their should be a way that can be faster then simply" re-processing all the existing message from beginning until find the specific offset"